# do not display list elements after click using Angular Observable and async

Tags: angular, observable

I have a search bar where the user enters the characters and using the Angular **Observable** with **HTTP GET** the user gets suggestions for similar keywords. Once the user clicks on the preferred suggestion the search form is filled with the clicked keyword.

However once the user clicks the keyword, the **Observable** suggestions list still remains. I wish to remove the list or hide the list when the user clicks on the keyword.

```
class SearchItem {
  constructor(public url: string,
              public translated: string
              ) {
  }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  apiRoot: string = 'http://hydra2.ikap.biba.uni-bremen.de:8092/detectMeaningLanguageSpecific';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  search(term: string): Observable<SearchItem[]> {
    let inpjson = {'keyword': term, 'language': 'en'}
    let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}?inputAsJson=${JSON.stringify(inpjson)}`;
    return this.http.get(apiURL)
        .map(res => {
          return res.json().conceptOverview.map(item => {
            return new SearchItem(
                item.url,
                item.translatedURL
            );
          });
        });
  }
}
```

**HTML Component**

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="search"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Enter search string"
           [formControl]="searchField" #searchbox>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="text-center">
  <p class="lead" *ngIf="loading">Loading...</p>
</div>

<ul class="list-group" *ngIf="searchField.value !== ''">
  <li class="list-group-item"
      *ngFor="let track of results | async" (click)="searchbox.value = track.translated">
      {{track.translated}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried adding

```
(click)="searchbox.value = track.translated; results = []"
```

however I get an error in the console stating the that since the `results` is empty the `async` pipe won't execute.

**[Plnkr for the Same](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0AOMhNZU9PjJEypy7sn?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do it maintain one variable `selected = false;`

That will become true once item is selected,

```
<li class="list-group-item"
      *ngFor="let track of results | async" 
      (click)="searchbox.value = track.translated; selected = true;"
      // make selected true on item selection
> 
      {{track.translated}}
</li>
```

and make it false again on `keydown`,

```
<input type="search"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Enter search string"
           (keydown)='selected = false; true;' // on keydown make selected false
           [formControl]="searchField" #searchbox>
```

At last change the condition with `selected` :

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngIf="searchField.value !== '' && !selected"> 
// list won't be shown if textbox is balnk or item is selected
```

Here is the link to [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xzQFxFdNHmvr7zifrHzg?p=preview).